# Angular 2 basics

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, angular

it's not really an issue rather something that frustrates me.

Can someone please explain:

1. Why angular loads these scripts in html and directly from
   node_modules [image]
2. Why I can't just import a module installed with npm which results in
   an error in zone.js which no one(even docs, from what I found) knows
   what it does(same with the rest of scripts loaded in html).

I really tried for more then an hour to load a single npm module, using import, require, configs in systemjs.config.js(stupid name! why it's called systemjs if its extension is .js!) in map/packages/paths and none of this successfully.

All of this from angular starter guide.

Comment: Well, you know that you can acctually move the scripts and change the `src` right?

Comment: Why not use `angular-cli` it will add every required reference for you

Comment: By the way, there is no need for `shim.min.js`, angular now has `core.js` that includes that functionality https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5755

Comment: Yeah sure but...what about version control, or require them in a main script.
node_modules stays local, what happen when you move your project to the server? Does it mean that you should go search for all these scripts in node_modules move them to another folder and then change the src  in html?

Comment: There is a `gulp` task that would move all the required libraries in a desired folder when deploying

Comment: That's not a good practice, from what I learned till now doing anything but requireing modules from node_modules folder is not a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

Is your problem that you are unable to get these files downloaded? Or is that you don't know why you need the files?

If the former, just have the package.json that the quickstart provides and run npm isntall.

If the latter, all of that information is here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/npm-packages.html

Comment: I have the files, ran npm install and started the project.
My concern is that I can't just npm install --save npm-module and later just import module from 'npm-module' and use it.